# GPS location update in background in android

Tags: android, gps

I would like to keep updating my current location every 5 minutes to my server. I don't want to do anything if the current location is same every 5mins.

Is there any library that can do the above for me?

I looked into littlefluffy example it is does what I require but when I change timings instead of 1 min to 5mins. It doesn't seem to work at all.

In the sample code:

The class file that extends application has the following code:

```
LocationLibrary.initialiseLibrary(getBaseContext(), 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, "mobi.littlefluffytoys.littlefluffytestclient");
```

Which is calls the GPS check every 1 min and force calls if there is no updates every 2 mins.

So I changed the timings to:

```
LocationLibrary.initialiseLibrary(getBaseContext(), 5 * 60 * 1000, 15 * 60 * 1000, "mobi.littlefluffytoys.littlefluffytestclient");
```

Call Gps location every 5 mins. But this calls every minute updates the same location everytime to server. Have anybody had the same problem?

Also:

https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

it says deprecated?

So looking for library that can help my problem in android?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks they are working in a v18 release, asking for help to test it.